# boost signals connection management

Tags: c++, boost-signals

I've been bashing my head for the last two nights trying to figure this out with no positive results. There is the thing, in boost signals, every time I want to connect, say, a member function of one class to another's class signal, I have to save the resulting connection in a variable if I want to disconnect later. If later on, I want to connect the same member function to some other class signal (the member function is still connected with the previous class signal) I have to save this new connection in order to manage it too. My question is, is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need to keep `connection` instances around, you should be able to disconnect from a signal by passing the original callable to `signal::disconnect`, as described in the [Boost.Signals tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html). With member functions the problem is rather the fact that you cannot pass them directly to `signal`, you either wrap them in custom function objects, which would then be available as arguments to `signal::disconnect` or you use [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html), which by itself wouldn't be very useful as you cannot conveniently declare its return type. However that problem can be solved using Boost.Bind together with [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html).

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank, Nicola. Who said StackOverflow ain't the best site in the galaxy :)

Answer (score 8):

### Scoped Connections

Alternatively you could assign the returned connection to a variable of type [signal::scoped_connection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/scoped_connection.html). It's a type of [connection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/connection.html) which automatically disconnects on destruction **or reassignment**. This effectively limits a signal-slot connection lifetime to a particular scope.

For example when you reassign myConnection, the previous connection is automatically disconnected:

```
scoped_connection myConnection = someObject.Signal.connect(MyHandler);
myConnection = totallyDifferentObject.Signal.connect(MyHandler);
```

### Automatic Connection Management

In our project, we usually declare member variables as scoped connections. So their scope matches the live time of the particular object instance the belong to. This is a convenient way to automatically disconnect any signals an object instance is connected to when it is being destructed. Without scoped connections you have to manually disconnect yourself in the destructor. If you neglect to disconnect instances when they're destroyed, you'll end up invoking invalid signal handlers which will crash your programs.