# How to save boost::signal::connections for later disconnects?

Tags: boost-signals

I want to implement a class that uses `boost::signal` for callbacks. Other objects can register their callback functions using `AddHandler()` and `RemoveHandler()` methods.

In [one SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7156488/111327) it is suggested that we track the `boost::signal::connection` objects returned from `connect()`, but [in another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7496645/111327) it is suggested that we don't! I'm not clear on how to manage the connections.

How would I be able to look up which `connection` to disconnect later when I only have the `slot_type`?

```
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef void Handler();
    void AddHandler(const boost::signal<Handler>::slot_type& aHandler) {
        mSignal.connect(aHandler);
    }
    void RemoveHandler(const boost::signal<Handler>::slot_type& aHandler) {
        mSignal.disconnect(aHandler); // compiler error!
    }
private:
    boost::signal<Handler> mSignal;
};
```

I want a caller to be able to do something like:

```
MyObject lMyObject;
lMySignaler.AddHandler(boost::bind(&MyObject::OnEvent, lMyObject));
...
lMySignaler.RemoveHandler(boost::bind(&MyObject::OnEvent, lMyObject));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `const boost::signal<Handler>::slot_type&` as my parameter type, I changed them to function pointers. Then I used the function pointers as the keys in a `std::map` to track the `boost::signals::connection`s. When the `RemoveHandler` is called I just called `disconnect` on the connection and erase the entry in the map.

Comment: hi, do you know why does disconnecting with slot_type cause compile time errors. thank you